# nunique compare two Pandas dataframe with duplicates and pivot them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My input:

```
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'frame':[ 1,1,1,2,3,0,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,8,9,9,10,],
                        'label':['GO','PL','ICV','CL','AO','AO','AO','ICV','PL','TI','PL','TI','PL','CL','CL','AO','TI','PL','ICV','ICV'], 
'user': ['user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1','user1']}) 
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'frame':[ 1, 1, 2, 3, 4,0,1,2,2,2,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,10,11],
                        'label':['ICV','GO', 'CL','TI','PI','AO','GO','ICV','TI','PL','ICV','TI','PL','CL','CL','CL','AO','AO','PL','ICV'],
'user': ['user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2','user2']})

    df_c = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

I trying compare two df, `frame` by `frame`, and check if `label` in `df1` existing in same `frame` in `df2`. And make some calucation with result (pivot for example)

That my code:

```
m_df = df1.merge(df2,on=['frame'],how='outer' )
m_df['cross']=m_df.apply(lambda row: 'Matched' 
                                            if row['label_x']==row['label_y'] 
                                            else 'Mismatched', axis='columns')
pv_m_unq= pd.pivot_table(m_df,
                      columns='cross',
                      index='label_x',
                      values='frame', 
                      aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique,fill_value=0,margins=True)


pv_mc = pd.pivot_table(m_df,
                      columns='cross',
                      index='label_x',
                      values='frame', 
                      aggfunc=pd.Series.count,fill_value=0,margins=True)
```

but this creates a some problem:
first, I can calqulate "simple" total (column `All`) of matched and missmatched as descipted in picture, or its "duplicated" as `AO` in `pv_m` or wrong number as in `CL` in `pv_m_unq`

[image]

and second, I think `merge` method as I use int not clever way, because I get if `frame`+`label` repetead in df(its happens often), in merged df I get number row in df1 X number of rows in df2 for this specific `frame`+`label`

I think maybe there is a smarter way to compare df and pivot them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the unexpected result on margin total because the margin is making use the same function passed to `aggfunc` (i.e. [`pd.Series.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) in this case) for its calculation and the values of `Matched` and `Mismatched` in these 2 rows are both the same as `1` (hence only one unique value of `1`). (You are currently getting the unique count of `frame` id's)

Probably, you can achieve more or less what you want by taking the **count** on them (including margin, `Matched` and `Mismatched`) instead of the unique count of `frame` id's, by using [`pd.Series.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html) instead in the last line of codes:

```
pv_m = pd.pivot_table(m_df,columns='cross',index='label_x',values='frame', aggfunc=pd.Series.count, margins=True, fill_value=0)
```

**Result**

```
cross    Matched  Mismatched  All
label_x                          
AO             0           1    1
CL             1           0    1
GO             1           1    2
ICV            1           1    2
PL             0           2    2
All            3           5    8
```

### Edit

If all you need is to have the `All` column being the sum of `Matched` and `Mismatched`, you can do it as follows:

Change your code of generating `pv_m_unq` without building margin:

```
pv_m_unq= pd.pivot_table(m_df,
                      columns='cross',
                      index='label_x',
                      values='frame', 
                      aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique,fill_value=0)
```

Then, we create the column `All` as the **sum** of `Matched` and `Mismatched` for each row, as follows:

```
pv_m_unq['All'] = pv_m_unq['Matched'] + pv_m_unq['Mismatched']
```

Finally, create the row `All` as the **sum** of `Matched` and `Mismatched` for each column and append it as the last row, as follows:

```
row_All = pd.Series({'Matched': pv_m_unq['Matched'].sum(), 
                     'Mismatched': pv_m_unq['Mismatched'].sum(), 
                     'All': pv_m_unq['All'].sum()}, 
                     name='All')

pv_m_unq = pv_m_unq.append(row_All)
```

**Result:**

```
print(pv_m_unq)

         Matched  Mismatched  All
label_x                          
AO             1           3    4
CL             1           2    3
GO             1           1    2
ICV            2           4    6
PL             1           5    6
TI             2           3    5
All            8          18   26
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but in the future this may lead to a calculation error (there are duplicates and will be overcountable)

Comment: @TeoK  I think you need to review your current approach of getting the unique count of frame id, whether this would lead to undercount instead.  This kind of logics is seldom seen, why ?  As I mentioned in my answer, the margin calculation always use the same `aggfunc` function as the value calculation, but these 2 calculation needs different formulas if you want to get a sum for the margin while give unique count for values.  Thus, a simple solution is to use also sum for the values.  Otherwise, you need to format and calculate the margin by complicated codes.  Think about it.

Comment: In my example its looks easy, but in real data its more complicated, large set with "duplicated" rows i.e. in same frame coud be diferent labels, so I need compare frame by frame in another set, but in `merge` method its raise X2 number of rows for each 'frame+label'. I trying `group_by(['frame'])['m_label'].unique` but wthout success.

Comment: @TeoK Perhaps you can make a new question of more realistic case of your complicated data (of course with crafting good sample data that can represent the true complication) and let members here to help out.

Comment: remade question to more like in the "real data"

Comment: @TeoK  Edited solution.  Take a look and see if this meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin()` function like this:

```
df3 =df1[df1.label.isin(df2.label)]
```